# Date Picker not able to populate the date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the date from the SQL database.All the fields are getting retrieved properly and getting populated in the text filed but the date alone is not getting populated because of the mismatch of the format.When i console the date it showing as "1997-03-22T18:30:00.000+0000"

I need to get only the date and populate in the text field

```
function _update(id){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://localhost:8888/booksdetail/'+id,
                    method:'GET',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#name').val(data.name);
                        $('#description').val(data.description);
                        $('#author').val(data.author);
                        $('#price').val(data.price);
                        $("#release_date").val(data.release_date);
                        console.log(data.release_date);
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                            alert(error);
                    }
                })
```

The HTML file is

```
<label for="release">release Date</label>
<input type="date" name="releasedate" id = "release_date" >
```

Comment: convert date into desired format in which `date` field accept

Comment: @Sai Can you share the back-end code for getting the date

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, though the split would extract only the date part of the timestamp, you can use the below formatting if you need to keep other part of the timestamp. However, the date picker would only pick dates alone, rest you may need to mask the data as 00:00 /etc. Generally, DB and UI interactions need a matching format. When accepting the date try printing the same on the console as well as back-end i/o file `EG. System.out.prinln in Java` then manually match it to the desired format.

```
$(function() {
$('#dtpickr').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm', //specify the format
    onSelect: function(formatteddate){

        var date1 = new Date(); 

        var hour = date1.getHours();
        hour = (hour < 10) ? ("0" + hour) : hour ;

        var min = date1.getMinutes();
        min = (min < 10) ? ("0" + min) : min ;

        var sec = date1.getSeconds();
        sec = (sec < 10) ? ("0" + sec) : sec ;

        formatteddate= formatteddate + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

        $('#dtpickr').val(formatteddate);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: date picker is not a function type Error